# What can I configure or enable to determine why systemd took a "stop" action on a service?

Tags: systemd, configuration

We have a systemd service unit that starts a third-party agent; call it "service c". The service unit functions correctly -- at least, as far as I can tell!
After a patching cycle, systemd starts this service unit (as expected) but then it turns around and *stops* the service unit about two seconds after it successfully started it. I have every reason to believe that the service started successfully the first time. When I log in after the reboot, I can see that the service is indeed not running; at that point, I can start the service unit manually (`systemctl start service-c`) and it starts the service as expected.

**I would like to find out why systemd thinks it should be stopping the service unit. What can I configure or enable to determine why systemd took the "stop" action?**

I am aware of the [systemd LogLevel option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-system.conf.html#LogColor=) and have already set it to "debug", up from the default of "info".

A similar idea is to set `Environment=SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug` in the service unit file, but I don't particularly need the *service* debugged, but rather systemd itself.

The service unit configuration is:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/service-c.service
[Unit]
Description=service c
After=network-online.target local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/local-path/start.service-c
ExecStop=/local-path/stop.service-c
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

... and the evidence is:

```
$ systemctl status service-c
● service-c.service - service c
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/service-c.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Wed 2021-04-07 17:49:30 EDT; 14h ago
  Process: 3162 ExecStop=/local-path/stop.service-c (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1319 ExecStart=/local-path/start.service-c (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1478 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

`/local-path` is an obfuscated version of a local directory on the system.

Since this has been an ongoing issue, after the last reboot I instrumented the "stop" wrapper script to log the process parent tree (using `pstree -a -A -l -p -s $$)`); that log file shows:

```
04/07/2021 17:49:19  stop.service-c:  
systemd,1 --switched-root --system --deserialize 22
  `-stop.service-c,3162 /local-path/stop.service-c
      `-pstree,3178 -a -A -l -p -s 3162
```

... where PID 3162 corresponds to systemd's invocation of the stop script. This looks to me like systemd is calling the ExecStop for the service.

systemd stops this service about two seconds after it has finished starting; the agent's log file has these timestamps:

```
04/07/2021 17:49:12  start.service-c:  Starting agent
04/07/2021 17:49:17  start.service-c:  startup success
04/07/2021 17:49:19  stop.service-c:  Executing from /agent/home as user
```

... ending in ...

```
04/07/2021 17:49:30  stop.service-c:  Finished with RC=0
```

... which corresponds to systemd's 17:49:30 timestamp for being "dead".

The "Restart=on-failure" directive would restart the service, but systemd tells me that the service started successfully:

```
Apr 07 17:49:10 hostname systemd[1]: Starting service c...
Apr 07 17:49:17 hostname systemd[1]: Started service c.
```

Since the service started cleanly, and since there's no attempt made by systemd to *restart* the service, I don't think the Restart parameter is coming into play.

Perhaps interesting, there's no corresponding "Stopping service c..." log from journalctl (as there is when I manually stop the service), yet evidence points to systemd calling the ExecStop.

I am currently running systemd 219.

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. You can extract log entries for `service-c`, `systemd`, ...

Comment: @waltinator - I've checked the journalctl logs and there's no explanation for *why* systemd thinks it should be stopping the service, only that it is. The journal logs for the service show that it's being started and stopped in correlation with systemd's view. The pertinent journalctl logs are in the question.

Comment: I don't know if it's useful, but I just noticed a *lack* of a "Stopping service c..." message in the journal. I've edited the question with that information.

Comment: Seems like an odd path: ExecStart=/local-path/start.service-c.  Is there directory with the path /local-path?

Comment: Yes, @Cinaed; it's been obfuscated slightly, but the service starts successfully by calling that script.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Careful that as a safety measure `ExecStop` is run when the main process exits regularly too. So to me all (including the lack of stopping msg) seems normal behavior for when a service ends spontaneously. Perhaps after the patch now your `ExecStart` command "double-`fork(2)`"s and the first fork, the one that counts for `systemd`, exits 0 by its own accord. As to why it would rather stay up when you start it manually I wouldn't know. Maybe at boot time something's missing for your agent, but that "something" comes up later on before you get a chance to start the service manually?

Comment: Is /local-path in your PATH? How about root?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see where you're going with that, @CinaedSimson. Systemd (and me, running them independently) successfully executes those /local-path scripts to both start and stop the agent. They are executable and properly sh-bang'd.

Comment: Okay, I thought you had a boot problem.

Comment: @LL3 I'd like to learn more about why/when/why systemd "runs ExecStop when the main process exits regularly". The start script exits 0, as far as I can tell -- systemd indicates that the service is started successfully. I don't have the real-time evidence for systemd's view of that initial startup cgroup, unfortunately, but that's why I'm asking here -- to gather more information about systemd's reasoning for the "Stop" action.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I was careful to include "After=...local-fs.target" because this local-path is a filesystem; I think the filesystem is mounted & found successfully. The system boots successfully and starts this service ... but then it (seems to) stop this service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to find out why systemd thinks it should be stopping the service unit. What can I configure or
> enable to determine why systemd took the "stop" action?

In order to see the live-state of a service you can:

- Use a `systemd-cgls -l <service-cgroup-path>` command: there you will see all the services's processes as they are at that moment. The service's cgroup path can be retrieved with `systemctl show -p ControlGroup <service-name>` command. In more recent versions of `systemd` (not in v219) you may also use the convenient `-u <service-name>` option of `systemd-cgls` in place of the service's cgroup path
- For detailed insight you may use the very verbose `systemctl show <service-name>` command: this will give loads of info regarding the service state as known by `systemd`, and from that info you can try to infer in more detail what is happening

To investigate the "suspect stop" case, it is correct to add those commands as `ExecStop` commands. You can simply add them **at the beginning** of your own `stop.service-c` script (if it is indeed a script).

Or alternatively you can add them as additional `ExecStop` commands on their own **before** your `stop.service-c` command, as in:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/local-path/start.service-c
ExecStop=-/bin/sh -c 'systemd-cgls -l -u %n && systemctl show %n'
ExecStop=/local-path/stop.service-c
Restart=on-failure
```

Note that the `%n` specifier is correctly handled by `systemd` also when it occurs within quoted strings.

Alternatively you can also:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/local-path/start.service-c
ExecStop=-/usr/bin/systemd-cgls -l -u %n
ExecStop=-/bin/systemctl show %n
ExecStop=/local-path/stop.service-c
Restart=on-failure
```

Note also the `-` prefixing the commands so as to ignore their exit status, just in case they failed for unfathomable reasons.

Naturally you might also use them as `ExecStartPost` commands, so as to ponder the live-state immediately after the service is considered "successfully started" by `systemd`. (again make to ignore their exit status or `systemd` will tear down the entire service if they fail).

With regard to `systemd-cgls`'s output run as `ExecStop` command, you should note whether the `MainPID` process still shows up at that time: if it does show up, then it proves that `ExecStop` really has been performed autonomously by `systemd` as you suggest. Else (if the `MainPID` process is *not* present in `systemd-cgls`'s output at "stop" time) it means that `ExecStop` has been run *as a result* of the `MainPID` process exiting on its own accord. *(See further below for additional reasoning)*. You might also want to pay attention to the PID numbers of the service's processes together with the PID numbers of the (now dead) `ExecStart` command to try and infer what `fork(2)`-ing has been going on since the service start and all along, because that is very relevant for a `type=forking` service in order to assess whether it is well-behaved. *(See further below for additional reasoning)*.

With regard to `systemctl show`'s output run as `ExecStop` command , I would say that the most relevant properties to pay attention to *in your particular case* are:

- `MainPID`: reads `0` if the service's main process has exited on its own accord, else reads the service's main process's PID if it is still alive and thus is indeed being stopped by `systemd`
- `ExecMainExitTimestamp`: reads the exit time in `date` format if the service's main process has exited on its own accord, else does not read at all if the process is still alive and thus is indeed being stopped by `systemd`
- `ExecMainExitTimestampMonotonic`: as above but reads in Linux's monotonic clock and reads `0` if the process is still alive
- `ExecMainCode`: this corresponds to the `code=` string in `systemctl status`<sup>1</sup>, only it reports the decimal value of the `CLD_*` symbols instead of their translations into english words: according to Linux's current values for `CLD_*` symbols (which is an `enum` starting from `1`), the `ExecMainCode` field reads `0` if the process is still alive and thus is indeed about to be stopped by `systemd`, else reads `1` if the process has already `_exit(2)`-ed on its own accord, `2` if it has been `kill(2)`-ed (in this use case clearly *not* by `systemd`), and so on

**Note** however that the above fields do *not* correspond to the service's *current* state if `systemd` was unable to detect the service's main process at the time of service start. *(see below for explanations)*. They would rather correspond to the most recent run for which `systemd` *was* able to accomplish the detection fully.

---

#### Further insights

In your reasoning I can see two key points that worth extra clarification:

**`type=forking` services**

`type=forking` services are particularly tricky for `systemd`, especially when using `GuessMainPID=yes` (the default, therefore what you're currently using for your agent). For these service types the `ExecStart` command is expected to `fork(2)` itself **once** and then exit while its forked process is expected to live long and prosper as the `MainPID` of the service. Else:

1. If such forked process rather forks again and then exits as well, delegating to its own "secondly" forked process(es) the responsibility to function as the actual service, `GuessMainPID` simply loses track and `systemd` simply believes the service has finished regularly and spontaneously, and thus accomplishes the duty of cleaning everything (i.e. run `ExecStop` etc.) but *without* logging the `Stopping service...` message because, as far as `systemd` is concerned, it only reacted to the service's deliberate exit
2. If instead the `ExecStart` *original* process `fork(2)`s twice (or more) before exiting, then `GuessMainPID` surrenders and `systemd` restrains from tearing everything down when the `ExecStart` *original* process finally exits. This is a better case because the service's actual processes survive, but it is not yet ideal because then `systemd` won't keep full track of events either, thus leading to e.g. inconsistent/incomplete journal logs at the least.

**`ExecStop` execution**

The `ExecStop` commands are run *also* when the `MainPID` process exits successfully on its own accord, as long as the main process had also *started* successfully (which is your case at hand). I understand that it seems counterintuitive but that is simply normal behavior by `systemd`: it simply deems a service's `ExecStop` command the preferred way to clean after that service, prior to resort to (by default, see `systemd.kill(5)`) sending a SIGTERM first and possibly a SIGKILL afterwards.

It doesn't say it so explicitly anywhere in the `systemd.service(5)` manpage, but it can be inferred by a few bits and pieces of documentation, especially those regarding the environment variables available to the `Exec*` commands. See the [`$SERVICE_RESULT`, `$EXIT_CODE` and `$EXIT_STATUS`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#%24SERVICE_RESULT) variables as to what values they can take, what semantic significance they have, and the fact that they are made available precisely to the `ExecStop` as well as the `ExecStopPost` commands.

Apart from non-explicit (or personal interpretation of the) documentation, let's look at the sources that perform that behavior. Taken from v219, [here is `service_sigchld_event()` invoking `service_enter_running()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v219/src/core/service.c#L2435) on an event referring to a child that is known to be in "running" state, and then the [latter function invoking the `service_enter_stop()`](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/v219/src/core/service.c#L1449) "stopping" action in all cases except for when `RemainAfterExit=yes` or `type=dbus` or the service's main process has not been detected *(see `type=forking` explanation above)* or the control-group is not healthy.

As to *why* the `systemd` people decided to do so I wouldn't know as I am not a `systemd` developer, but I can see the usefulness of this behavior so as to give to all still alive-yet-"unknown" processes of a service their chance to be notified about their imminent termination in the nicest possible way, before getting a harsh SIGTERM and SIGKILL as per `systemd`'s last resort as it proceeds to close the whole control-group. This measure is particularly useful precisely for `type=forking` services because those are the most difficult for `systemd` to track down correctly, as explained in the `type=` paragraph of `systemd.service(5)`, and because `systemd` tries to clean after legacy/lazy/poorly-implemented services that don't close gracefully before exiting.

HTH

---

<sup>1. `code=` followed by a word representing the "exit reason" of the process: whether it `exited` or has been `killed` or `trapped` or even `dumped`; in practice: literally a word translating the various `CLD_*` values valid for [the `siginfo_t.si_code` field as described in `sigaction(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)</sup>

Comment: This is helpful information; thank you! I'm going to instrument the unit file with the ExecStop and ExecStartPost suggestions. Hopefully that answers the question at-hand. I have trouble believing that systemd silently stopped the service with no (logging) mention of "Stopping service-c...", but that certainly seems to be the evidence at this point. I will dig into the source code to see if that's a possibility.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I didn't want to be too bold in the answer but I'm rather convinced that it's the other way around, as I had also hinted in my comment to your question: systemd ran ExecStop _as a consequence_ of the MainPID process exiting spontaneously. IOW systemd did _not_ stop the service, but it ran ExecStop simply for "after-exit", extra-cleaning, purposes as per its normal (yet under-documented) behavior. In those cases systemd does not log any "Stopping.." message. Please feel free to edit my answer if you see fit to make anything clearer (I'm also not native english speaker)

Comment: I'm happy to be wrong! :) I just wanted to get some evidence to make the situation clearer. I like your theory that the MainPID exited cleanly, causing systemd to call ExecStop; I haven't seen this agent (or its wrapper script) do such a thing, but perhaps there's something else going on.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Certainly! It's absolutely fair wishing to have more insight on the live situation so as to see it actually happening. Besides, I can't be totally sure either, because the thing that if you start the service manually then it stays up defies my theory completely.

Comment: Really late follow-up; this answer helped us resolve the issue. *"systemd ran ExecStop as a consequence of the MainPID process exiting spontaneously"* is the main idea, combined with the fact that the agent's start script (itself a shell script) calls *another* shell script which then starts the agent processes. I believe, based on my notes, that systemd was *sometimes* able to track the MainPID and other times not -- leading to occasional ExecStop's. I updated the outer startup script to write out a PIDFile (under /run) containing the "main" agent process, and that's been working.