# What events cause ExecStop script to run in systemd?

Tags: linux, systemd, rhel

We have a systemd service that invokes several tomcat instances.

```
[Unit]
Description=Tomcat Services
After=network.target multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/users/mwe/scripts/appstart.sh
ExecStop=/users/mwe/scripts/appstop.sh
Restart=on-abort
User=webapp
Group=webgrp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

We patched/rebooted a system and the service came up as expected.

```
Jul 10 20:38:02 a8cc08d appstart.sh[5989]: [AA00001654][AA00001654_PRD] - Remove all log files older than 90 days ...
Jul 10 20:38:03 a8cc08d appstart.sh[5989]: [etp][ciiprod] - Remove all log files older than 90 days ...
Jul 10 20:38:03 a8cc08d appstart.sh[5989]: [etp][ciiprod] -----------------------------
...
Jul 10 20:38:08 a8cc08d systemd[1]: Started Tomcat Services.
```

However, about 22.5 hours later, the ExecStop script was run, apparently by systemd.

```
Jul 11 19:00:07 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: [etp][ciiprod] -----------------------------
Jul 11 19:00:48 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: [2.0K blob data]
Jul 11 19:00:48 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: Completed execution of . / tcruntime-ctl.sh
Jul 11 19:00:48 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: [oasys][ciiprod] -----------------------------
Jul 11 19:00:48 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: tcServer is not running for environment: ciiprod.
Jul 11 19:00:48 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: Completed execution of . / tcruntime-ctl.sh
Jul 11 19:00:48 a8cc08d appstop.sh[29451]: [report][ciiprod] -----------------------------
```

There are no users logged in at this time, no cron jobs configured, no autosys jobs, etc. We are stumped as to why systemd would have invoked the ExecStop script on its own, if this is what happened. I have read that ExecStop would be run if the service "crashed", but how does it determine this, and wouldn't systemd report the service failure in the logs? We tested killing the application process with every kill signal, and could not replicate this behavior. It would either restart (Restart=on-abort) or just report failed (when killed cleanly), and always record the failure in the logs. We know 'systemctl stop' was not run, as that would insert "Stopping" and the service description into the log, which it did not. All that appears is the output of the appstop.sh script (ExecStop).

RHEL 7.9. We have a case open with Red Hat, but I don't have high confidence they will dig into systemd and find an answer.

**Update:** More findings, there is an Autosys job that shuts down and restarts ONE of the tomcat instances, and the times correspond to when appstop.sh is running. When an instance is stopped outside of systemd, is it possible that systemd thinks the entire cgroup is unhealthy or the service crashed and is trying to clean up? I've tried to replicate this by inventing a service that runs some background "sleep" processes. However, I can kill off all the sleeps but the last remaining one, and systemd doesn't care. When I kill the last one of course systemd logs the failed service.

Comment: This sounds similar to a situation I ran across recently in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/644160/what-can-i-configure-or-enable-to-determine-why-systemd-took-a-stop-action-on; the going theory is that with a forking unit that starts through a series of shell scripts, systemd guesses what the main/surviving pid is. If it guesses wrong and that pid disappears, it considers the unit failed and runs the ExecStop to clean up. See the commands in the linked answer; I used them to gather more information. Setting debug levels in systemd turned out to be useless for me.

Comment: Try adding a `PIDFile=/some/file` in the `[Service]` section, and keep in it the pid of a process in your tomcat setup that must exist and does not disappear or change, so systemd knows if the unit is ok.